# How to return a dataframe with float and str type columns when using the pandas series expanding apply method?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply, series

I have a series.  I want to apply a function to the expanding version of this series and return a two column dataframe.  The first column is of type float and the second column is of type str.  However, the method seems upset that I am attempting to enter a str as we roll through the apply function, seemingly because it has already populated the column further up with np.nans i.e. float objects and will not then let me deploy the string in the column.

Here is an example illustrating the issue:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])

a.expanding(2).apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x,'string'],index=['float','string']))
```

returns the error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

The desired result would be:

```
 float  string
0  nan  nan
1   2   test
2   3   test
3   4   test
4   5   test
```

and I suspect the error is a result of attempting to formulate the string column as a mixture of float and str, whereas the float column remains as all float type.

If I remove the expanding aspect, then it does function as expected:

```
a.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x,'test'],index=['float','string']))
```

returns

```
 float  string
0   1   test
1   2   test
2   3   test
3   4   test
4   5   test
```

I have tried to set a as an object as follows:

```
a.astype(object).expanding(2).apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x,'test'],index=['float','string']))
```

However this results in the same error as above.

I have also tried to use the convert_dtype parameter from the series.apply method, but this does not seem to work at all.  In fact it returns the following error:

```
TypeError: apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert_dtype'
```

If someone could explain the exact issue and suggest how to get the desired outcome that would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: The [x,'test'] is an example output from the function that I would be applying that will return a list with a float and a string.  The function needs to take the expanding float series as an input, specifically with a minimum of 7 data points (note: the series is shorter here just for the example), but the point is there must be a minimum for the expanding series, which I assume necessitates some np.nans further up, if this is indeed the issue.

Comment: Right. It would also be easier to help if your example showed why `expanding` is necessary for what you are trying to accomplish (the point of the method is to accumulate values one way or another, I don't see that in the expected output). Cheers.